# Bootstrap carousel Not functional

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-carousel

I'm working in Laravel 5.5 which is bundled with Bootstrap and I have my main JS file running appropriately (i.e. laravel mix compiling with all the all the js files loaded with it appropriately). However, bootstrap 3.3.7's carousel is not working at all. The transitions (slide actions) don't work and the buttons dont work at all. here's my code below

```js
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

require('./animations');

window.Vue = require('vue');

// *
//  * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
//  * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
//  * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.


Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
  el: '.content'
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js') }}"></script>
<!-- Styles -->
<link href="{{ asset('css/main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> . .. ...
<div class="container-fluid content">
  <div class="carousel slide" id="features">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#features" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#features" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#features" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="/images/niceview.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h4 class="carousel-header">Lorem Ipsum</h4>
          <p class="carousel-text">Some Lorem ipsum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="/images/rear.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h4 class="carousel-header">Dreams</h4>
          <p class="carousel-text">Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="/images/view.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h4 class="carousel-header">Dreams</h4>
          <p class="carousel-text">Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#features" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#features" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

That's my js file which compiles successfully by mix and my html file. And right now I don't get any errors in the console so I have no clue as to what is wrong.

Please help :(

Comment: I guess jquery needs to be loaded before bootstrap, can you check if this is the order in which you are loading libraries

Comment: I have jquery loaded outside the js file. You will see it at the top of the html page in my code.

Comment: Also, does the carousel work outside Laravel as plain html/js? In your html the div class="carousel-inner" has child div class="item" but in bootstrap example they call it carousel-item.. https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap carousal in the blade file.

add this to your filename.blade.php

```
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="{{ asset('public/images/1.jpg')}}" alt="" style="width:100%;">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="{{ asset('public/images/2.jpg')}}" alt="" style="width:100%;">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="{{ asset('public/images/3.jpg')}}" alt="" style="width:100%;">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

add this css file like this

```
<link href="{{ asset('public/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

and add js like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('public/js/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('public/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
```

using this following step carousal is work.

i hope this will help you to solve your problem

Comment: Thanks Niket but the javascript code I have above contains the bootstrap Javascript file. It's one of the files that is required and dumps everything into one large JS file.